# how can I get notification on my webpage when I am online in gmail or facebook?

Tags: facebook, web-services, notifications, gmail, alert

I want to create one feature for my website page. that is when I am logged into my gmail account at that time I want to notify or blinking on my web page.
Is it possible? if yes, then plz answer how? tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you need to add your google or facebood account status in your page.
**Google:** Add this line to your page

```
<script src='//talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/button'></script>
```

**Facebook:** *Answer from [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090219040351AAajdta)* 
Facebook has a Twitter-like feature in which you can update your "status" -- a one-liner formatted as [whatever you type].

It's now possible to export your Facebook status as an RSS feed, which means you can add it to your own choice site.

The hard part is finding your personal status "feed." Go to your Facebook Profile page and look for the "Mini-Feed" box. Click on the "See all" link. On the right rail of the resulting page is a list of links; one of them is "Status stories." That's the one you want. Click it.

Now you have a page labeled "My Mini-Feed" that is limited to your own status updates. Look in the right rail for an RSS icon and a label, "Subscribe to these stories." There's your RSS link.

Grab the URL and add it to the Aggregator on your website. Set the refresh time to the lowest possible value (15 minutes) and make sure cron runs at least that frequently.

Currently, the Aggregator module produces a block for each feed. You can place that block in any region. Voila: Your Facebook status is now reflected on your website.

Comment: in facebook I did not able to find mini-feed option. and for gmail.it shows button but I want to blink just that I m online now!!

Comment: Well this is the script google team provided. If you want something else (blinking, ...) you should write your own script.

Comment: yeah, that I know, but I mean Is there any method or code which returns current status of my different account?

Comment: If you want to know how to write these scripts, then better to change the question or ask another.